# why java script cannot access this asp.net var?

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery

I have this c# user control class:

```
public partial class UserControls_JsTop : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    public static string sidebarBannerUrl = getSideBarBannerImgUrl();

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    public static string getSideBarBannerImgUrl(){
        DataClassesDataContext db = new DataClassesDataContext();
        var imgUrl = (from b in db.Banners
                      where b.Position.Equals(EBannersPosition.siderbar.ToString())
                      select b).FirstOrDefault();
        if (imgUrl != null)
            return imgUrl.Path;
        return String.Empty;

    }
}
```

I try to acces the static var in a js script:

load it here:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var categoryParam = '<%# CQueryStringParameters.CATEGORY %>';
    var subcategory1Param = '<%# CQueryStringParameters.SUBCATEGORY1_ID %>';
    var subcategory2Param = '<%# CQueryStringParameters.SUBCATEGORY2_ID %>';
    var imgUrl = '<%# UserControls_JsTop.sidebarBannerUrl %>';
</script>
```

and use it here (imgUrl):

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(function () {
        $(document.body).sidebar({
            size: "30px", // can be anything in pixels
            length: "270px", // can be anything in pixels
            margin: "300px", // can be anything in pixels
            position: "left", // left / bottom / right / top
            fadding: "0.8", // 0.1 to 1.0 
            img: imgUrl,
            openURL: "www.twitter.com/amitspatil"
        });
    }); 

 </script>
```

I do not understand why it is empty.
Please trust me that there is a record in DB with that condition.

I think there is some js problem when loading the var...

Do you know where?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `#` to `=` to use a normal expression instead of a databound one.

Comment: is not this enough?  return HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute(imgUrl.Path));